# Avoiding for loops, interpolate over a dimension of a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, 3d

I have a large 3D numpy array of dimensions (l, n, m) with elements which correspond to 1D arrays of x, y and z with dimensions l, n and m respectively. I would like to find the elements at given values of a (with length b) by interpolating between the values of z for each combination of x and y. This would give an output 3D array of dimensions (l, n, b). I would like to this completly using numpy arrays rather than resorting to for loops.

For example if my 3D array had dimensions (2,3,4):

```
x = 1 | z = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
y = 1 |[[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],       
y = 2 |  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
y = 3 |  [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

x = 2 | z = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
y = 1 | [[ 12, 13, 14, 15],        
y = 2 |  [ 16, 17, 18, 19],
y = 3 |  [ 20, 21, 22, 23]]]
```

I would like to interpolate across each row {(x=1, y=1), (x=1, y=2), (x=1, y=3), (x=2, y=1), (x=2, y=2), (x=2, y=3)} for values of a = [1.3, 1.8, 2.34, 2.9, 3.45] to give a 3D array of dimensions (2,3,5):

```
[[[  0.3,  0.8,  1.34,  1.9,  2.45],
  [  4.3,  4.8,  5.34,  5.9,  6.45],
  [  8.3,  8.8,  9.34,  9.9, 10.45]],

 [[ 12.3, 12.8, 13.34, 13.9, 14.45],
  [ 16.3, 16.8, 17.34, 17.9, 18.45],
  [ 20.3, 20.8, 21.34, 21.9, 22.45]]]
```

Currently I use a for loop to iterate over each combination of x and y and feed the row of my 3D array into the numpy.iterpolate function and save the output into another array; this is however very slow with large arrays.

```
# array is the 3D array with dimensions (l, n, m)
# x, y and z have length l, n and m respectively
# a is the values at which I wish to interpolate at with length b
# new_array is set up with dimensions (l, n, b) 

new_array = N.zeros(len(x)*len(y)*len(a)).reshape(len(x), len(y), len(a))
for i in range(len(x)):
      for j in range(len(y)):
               new_array[i,j,:] = numpy.interpolate(a, z, array[i,j,:])
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you consider scipy.interpolate.griddata ?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way... `np.interp` only takes 1D inputs, and even if you tried to construct the interpolation from scratch, `np.searchsorted`, which is the obvious option to find the bin in which to interpolate, also works only on 1D arrays.

Comment: Yes, it only works for 2D, if you read the doc (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) it states that the points you input are (N, ndim) - so again that would require a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop to run you data through `scipy.interpolate.griddata`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>>from scipy.interpolate import griddata

>>> data = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)

>>> x = np.arange(1, 3)
>>> y = np.arange(1, 4)
>>> z = np.arange(1, 5)
>>> points = np.array(list(product(x, y, z)))

# This is needed if your x, y and z are not consecutive ints
>>> _, x_idx = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
>>> _, y_idx = np.unique(y, return_inverse=True)
>>> _, z_idx = np.unique(z, return_inverse=True)
>>> point_idx = np.array(list(product(x_idx, y_idx, z_idx)))
>>> values = data[point_idx[:, 0], point_idx[:, 1], point_idx[:, 2]]

>>> new_z = np.array( [1.3, 1.8, 2.34, 2.9, 3.45])
>>> new_points = np.array(list(product(x, y, new_z)))
>>> new_values = griddata(points, values, new_points)
>>> new_values.reshape(2, 3, -1)
array([[[  0.3 ,   0.8 ,   1.34,   1.9 ,   2.45],
        [  4.3 ,   4.8 ,   5.34,   5.9 ,   6.45],
        [  8.3 ,   8.8 ,   9.34,   9.9 ,  10.45]],

       [[ 12.3 ,  12.8 ,  13.34,  13.9 ,  14.45],
        [ 16.3 ,  16.8 ,  17.34,  17.9 ,  18.45],
        [ 20.3 ,  20.8 ,  21.34,  21.9 ,  22.45]]])
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Just one thing, when I try it myself, the product function you have used is not recognised. Is that a numpy function? The numpy.prod() function I am familiar with does not take three consecutive arrays. Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to add the `from itertools import product` and `from scipy.interpolate import griddata` at the top of the code, edited it!